# How do I get IIS Express to work in Windows 8?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, iis-express

So I've been working at this for about 2 days now and have essentially hit a dead end.  I guess the first thing to know is, can IIS Express work in combination with Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 8?

I just got this new laptop in, with Windows 8 pre-installed.  I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, SP1, and MVC 3.  I had to enabled .NET Framework 4.0 myself...

I have a project that I transferred from my old computer (windows 7) to this computer.  It was set up to run on IIS Express.  So when I opened the project, VS2010 said that I was missing some components and asked if I wanted to install them--so it installed IIS Express for me.   When I try to run my project, I get a "This page can't be displayed" page in IE.  In fiddler, I get
 - 302 HTTP localhost:16683 /
 - 502 HTTP Tunnel to localhost:443

the SSL URL for the project is `https://localhost:44300/`
the URL for the project is `http://localhost:16683/`

If I go to IISExpress in my system tray and select the https link there, it opens the website up just fine.  If I select the http link there, it get that "502 HTTP Tunnel to localhost:443" line in fiddler again...  Why is it trying to tunnel to localhost:443???

Another thing to note is that I decided to create a test MVC 3 project from scratch to see what IIS Express would do.  I set the project to run on IIS without enabling SSL.  When I run the project is starts up just fine.  When I click the logon link, it tries to redirect to an https link with port 44300...when it shouldn't be.  I created a test project for the same purpose on my windows 7 machine, and the project did not do this.

The last thing to note is that after going to the https link for my initial project via the IIS Express tray icon, if I click the logon link for the test project, it now takes me to my initial project's https link...  It's as if the projects are crossing over into each other...

Comment: Your question is answered in the [**SuperUser Forum**: Visual Studio 2010 not compatible?](http://superuser.com/questions/493159/visual-studio-2010-not-compatible)

Comment: @balexandre what does that have to do with iis express?

Comment: Your 302 showing up - whats the target of the 302, the 443? If so your app is sending out the localhost:443 in which case I'd say look in your web.config for auth redirect for your forms auth url, if you have no url defined, maybe explicitly define it there.

Comment: @AdamTuliper cause it's free and a simple test as from the answer on SuperUser, 2010 is not fully compatible with Windows 8...

Comment: The posted link has nothing at all to do with this issue here (ssl/redirects). If you follow through to Microsoft's site, you'll see the issue is described as related to tests: "Hi there - VS 2010 does indeed have an incompatibility with Win8 - The scenario for the incompatibility was around the test tools so in general VS 2010 will run after install on Win8 - This issue was addressed in this GDR (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182)."

Comment: @Adam Tuliper  
The URL for the 302 is a simple forward slash: /  
I'm not sure if that's what you mean by "target"  
  
In the <authentication> section of my web.config, I have a <forms> element that specifies a loginUrl.  Is this what you're referring too when you say, "your web.config for auth redirect for your forms auth url"?
  
I just can't think of why it would want to go to port 443 and why I'm getting a 502 error...  If it were to try to go to the SSL port defined in the project (44300), everything would work just dandy, So this appears to be the main issue...  Any other ideas?

Comment: @balexandre - It might have something to do with windows 8 and IIS Express.  The only way I could confirm something like this is to try the same setup on another computer with windows 7 and then maybe another computer with windows 8?

Comment: UPDATE: So realizing that the issue had to do with the redirecting not working correctly, I added some <rewrite> stuff to my config file under <system.webServer>. I remember having to do this at some point with my project a long while ago when I was developing it on my old computer in Windows 7.  But at some point, I was able to remove the <rewrite> element and I don't remember why.  Not sure what the deal is.  Here's an example of the url <rewrite> I'm talking about: http://www.jphellemons.nl/post/AspNet-switch-site-to-SSL-(https)-the-easy-way.aspx

I'm not sure I consider this the answer tho

Comment: Anyone else got any other ideas that may be IIS Express "configuration" related for Windows 8?  Or will I just have to settle for the rewrite in my config file on development and remove it in release?

Comment: I came back to say that my issue has been resolved.  Not sure how.  The last thing I did was to go back to my old computer, unbind the solution from TFS there, move it to my new computer, and then bind it to TFS.  Works without modification now.